# mbox still shows mail messages after they have been deleted

Tags: mailx, mail-command

I deleted all messages from my mail with `mailx d MSGS`, and now `mailx` shows no mail.

But why does `cat ~/mbox` still show all of the supposedly deleted messages?

Answer (score 1):

What version of mailx are you using ? What UNIX/Linux OS are you using ? There are mailx variants.... what is your OS, that might help as well.

Note that I found this in the man page of mailx, not sure this is the issue you are encountering, because afaics, the mailx variant of this man page does not accept the `d` switch on the command line, I might be mistaken, though.

`Deletion causes the mailx program to forget about the message. This is not irreversible;`